# Call a class with a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is probably a silly question.

I have this class

```
<div class="about_us aperto">
```

how do I call it in a JS function?
I'm trying:

```
$('.about_us aperto').click(function(){...
$('.about_us .aperto').click(function(){...
```

but they do not work.

Comment: you can do it like this `$('.about_us.aperto').click(function(){...` , remove the spaces in between

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect them. The proper selector would be:

```
$('.about_us.aperto')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to select an element having multiple classes like `<div class="classA classB ClassC"></div>` then just join them together in JavaScript i.e. `$('.classA.classB.classC').click(function() {...});`

```js
$('.about_us.aperto').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about_us aperto">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```